# Redirect SSAS traffic from Machine 1 to Machine 2

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2

Machine 1 & Machine 2 both have SSAS instances (listening on default port, 2383), one each.

When users try to connect to Machine 1, SSAS instance they should be redirected to Machine 2, SSAS instance. How can this be done - Port Forwarding, Network Load Balancing?

Note: The OS is Windows Server 2008 R2 & the machines are Hyper-V Virtual Machines

Answer (score 0):

[Look at this link](http://sqlcat.com/sqlcat/b/technicalnotes/archive/2010/02/08/microsoft-sql-server-2008-analysis-services-consolidation-best-practices.aspx).

If you review the article, you will find the ASLB solution that SQLCAT used to load balance, but it could be used on Machine 1, so that it redirects to Machine 2. It might be overkill for your solution, but you can download it and install it now.